# Move ax.text a bit away from data point

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a type of map that plots a route between points.
As such I have something that looks like the image below:

[image]

And as you can see, the `bll` label is very close to the data point. I would like it to be a bit further away, so you can actually see the dot.

Also, the text is just a regular `ax.text` plot with `x` and `y` values.

My problem is, that yes, I could just add some kind of percentage value or something. However, depending on the coordinate and x-value, this will not be the same depending on you being very far left, where x => 0, or far right where x => max value of the plot. Then you could argue I could just add 10 or 20 units, but in my case I produce different maps depending on different routes. So this means that the x-axis values are not the same. Sometimes the map is big, and sometimes it's small. So using the same value in all maps will make `bll` text move either very much or very little depending on size.

Also, if I am ever to zoom on the map, this would adjust the text as well if I were to use some kind of value extension, since the distance between the data point AND the text will also increase relative to the size of the zoom, like this figure:

[image]

Can this be solved in a somewhat simple manner ?

Best regards

Comment: you might look into using [`ax.annotate`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/annotations.html) instead. You can define the `xy` location, then use `textcoords='offset pixels` to offset the text from that point. See here for examples: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/annotation_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-text-labels-and-annotations-annotation-demo-py

Comment: A simple trick could be to add a space to the text.  `ax.text(x, y, " "+"text", ha='left', va='center')` or `ax.text(x, y, "text"+" ", ha='right', va='center')`.

Comment: @JohanC that is one simple good trick I didn't think of. Thanks man. Feel free to make an Answer if you want, and I'll accept.